# How to disable warning: binary constants are a GCC extension

Tags: gcc, suppress-warnings

How to disable "warning: binary constants are a GCC extension" ?

I have active -Wextra -pedantic and want to disable above warning? How to do it without unintentionally disable some other warning?

Answer (score 4):

Generally you can find out which switch controls which warning with the option

```
-fdiagnostics-show-option
```

But this warning says:

```
warning: binary constants are a GCC extension [enabled by default]
```

Being an extension means, it is enabled with -pedantic

Here: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23479#c3 it has been discussed to add the warning to -Wgcc-extensions, but that switch doesn't exist.

From the manual at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions

> GNU C provides several language features not found in ISO standard C. (The -pedantic option directs GCC to print a warning message if any of these features is used.) To test for the availability of these features in conditional compilation, check for a predefined macro **GNUC**, which is always defined under GCC.